# Databricks- Autoincrement identity- How to insert the changes from latest cdf version

Tags: insert, azure-databricks, auto-increment

I have an autoloader table processing a mount point with CSV files.
After each run, I would like to insert some of the records into another table where I have an AutoIncrement Identity column set up.

I can rerun the entire insert and this works, but I am trying to only insert the newest records.

I have CDF enabled, so I should be able to determine the latest version, or maintain the versions processed. But it seems like I am missing some built in feature of Databricks.

Any suggestions or sample to look at?

Answer (score 0):

> Note - Delta change data feed is available in Databricks Runtime 8.4
> and above.

You can read the change events in batch queries using SQL and DataFrame APIs (that is, df.read), and in streaming queries using DataFrame APIs (that is, df.readStream).

**Enable CDF**

```
%sql
ALTER TABLE silverTable SET TBLPROPERTIES (delta.enableChangeDataFeed = true)
```

> Any suggestions or sample to look at?

You can find Sample Notebook [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/_static/notebooks/delta/cdf-demo.html)